# In bash script parameter tracking

Tags: bash

I have this command in `bash`:

```
cmd -c -s junk text.txt
```

If I change the command to

```
cmd -c junk -s text.txt
```

how to I keep track which parameter (`$2` or `$3`) is set to `junk`?.

I try to use a for loop but I don't know how to find out `junk` from `$@`.

Comment: Is `cmd` a function in bash? What other lines follow from it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [getopts](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/getopts/) inside your script. Something like this should work:

```
while getopts "c:s:" optionName; do
   case "$optionName" in
   s) arg="$OPTARG"; echo "-s is present with [$arg]";;
   c) arg="$OPTARG"; echo "-c is present with [$arg]";;
   esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example you show it seems that the `-s` option has a single argument and that is `junk` in the first example. However the semantics seems to change in the second example and there apparently `-c` takes a single argument and it is again `junk`. Also in the second example it seems `-s` takes `text.txt` as argument.

In general the arguments in bash commands do not have fixed positions but if an option takes an argument it should directly follow the option parameter(in the first case `-s`).

As pointed out by anubhava you may use getopts to parse the arguments for your script. Still this will not work for the case where you change the whole semantics like it seems you do.